# Injecting one service in another service angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Can i use one service into another angular service? Else what will be the best approach to accomplish the below?

First Service:

```
var app = angular.module("MyApp", []);
app.service('Service1', function () {
    return {
        FirstFunction: function () {
            return "something";
        }
    }
});
```

Second service:

```
app.service('Service2', function () {
    return {
        SecondFunction: function () {
           //How to use FirstFunction of Service1 ???
        }
    }
});
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
app.service('Service2', function (Service1) {
    return {
        SecondFunction: function () {
           Service1.FirstFunction();
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks alot.Works great. I just tried the below which didnt work. What is the reason.                                                     app.service('Service2',["Service1", function (Service1) {
    return {
        SecondFunction: function () {
           Service1.FirstFunction();
        }
    }
}]);

Answer (score 3):

```
app.service('Service2', function (Service1) {
    return {
        SecondFunction: function () {
           Service1.FistFunction
        }
    }
});
```

As long as service2 doesnt depend on service1 there is no problem.